# JPanel super.pantComponent(Graphics g) not clear my panel as wanted

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

This is the code to draw some shape in my panel. My idea is: at paint event startup, clear the panel, if any "plotter" have "isDraw = true", I will paint it. But when running, I changed the variable (see throw debug), but the panel doesn't clear any thing, all line are still be there. How can I do it?

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        // setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        drawAxis(g);
        for (PlotterSin plotter : allPlotter) {
            if (plotter.isDraw()) {

            Polygon p = new Polygon();
            Polygon p2 = new Polygon();

            for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
                p.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int) (50 * plotter.func((x / 100.0) * 2 * Math.PI)));

            }

            g.setColor(plotter.getColor());
            g.drawPolyline(p.xpoints, p.ypoints, p.npoints);
            g.drawString("-2\u03c0", 95, 115);
            g.drawString("2\u03c0", 305, 115);
            g.drawString("0", 200, 115);
        }
        // g.setColor(Color.blue);
        // g.drawPolyline(p2.xpoints, p2.ypoints, p2.npoints);
    }

}
```

Comment: The `super.paintComponent()` should do the job, but we can't see the context of your class is used. Are you sure you are extending JPanel and and not JComponent? Are you sure the JPanel is opaque (which it is by default)? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if the suggestions don't help.

Comment: Did you call `repaint` after changing the variable?

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  Oh, my mistake is not recall the repaint(), I thought it is called repeatly like a game draw method, I manuall call it, now I worked. Thankyou

Comment: Swing uses a passive rendering engine, updating only when it needs to

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to call repaint() of the JFrame contain that Jpanel after change. The jpanel's paintComponent() only work after it's parent repaint() called